# How to connect own class to UITabBar element?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I created `UITabBarController` at storyboard.
Also I have created the separated class.

How I can connect my empty class to `UITabBarController`, that to make settings of `TabBar` in section:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 // Change background TabBar at whole project
 // Set border bottom for selected item
}
```

I tried to set name class in storyboard for `TabBar`, but it does not allow

Answer (score 1):

First : You create your custom class who is a subclass of UITabBarController

Then : in your nib file

[image]

You can set your new custom class to your nib. For example, AFSTVolumeDetailViewHeader in the image below. Don't forget to press enter after you put the name of your class and check if it works by pressing the arrow next to the name of the class.

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to make settings for BarTab where to do this? For example I need to set common style for selected tabs

Comment: You can make setting directly into your nib at attribute inspector. Or you can do it programaticaly into the method : - (void) awakeFromNib. Don't forget to validate my answer if it helped you thx !

Comment: Where is it? I mean that I have some tabs items and I dont want to set settings for each. I need to configure it globally in one file

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard select your UITabBarController. Then in the right pane select the Identity Inspector. Enter your class name in the Class field.

If the inspector doesn't allow you to enter your custom class make sure that your custom class is a subclass of UITabBarController.

[image]